# Watch mp4 from phone remotely pc

Tags: windows-7, android, webserver, mp4

I have lot of mp4 in my windows laptop, and I have android  phone.

I want to watch those mp4 from my  android.

How can I simply create a server in windows laptop so I can watch videos from my android.

The laptop and android  in same network.

Comment: Would it be possible to just use a USB to USB-micro or USB-C? (Depending on phone) that would make it much easier to access all files.

Comment: Share the folder and use a media player that support Windows share on the phone. Another way is to install some SW that have both Windows side media server app and phone side media player app. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to a file server from Android, but there are *significant* performance penalties because Android is not designed to access networked files rapidly. You are far better off downloading the file from the server into the Android, then watching the local copy of the video file.